# Looking for a way to launch a batch file if a particular string exists in a text file

Tags: perl, batch-file

I am looking for a way to launch a batch file if a particular string exists in a text file. For example - i want to check file.txt for the string 'working'. if it exists - i would like to launch a batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "unable to open '$file' for reading :$!";

while(my $line = <$fh>){
    chomp($line);
    if($line =~ /working/){
       my $result = qx/some.bat/;  # use backtick or system()
       last;
    }
}

close($fh);
```

Comment: This solution could run the batch file multiple times for the same input file.  You're better off consuming the whole file into a variable then searching that variable once.  It would also be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
my $data = do {
    open my $in, "<", "file.txt" or die "Could not open: $!";
    local $/;
    <$in>
};

if($data =~ /working/) {
    system("cmd", "/c batch.cmd");
}
```